# Validate dropdownlistfor MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having problems trying to validate a drop down list, I've looked at similar questions on here and tried the suggestions but still no luck. One I haven't tried is making my Benefit Id nullable, but is that a good idea? many thanks

Model I'm trying to validate:

```
public class Benefit
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }


}
```

View model:

```
public class LookupVm
{
    public SelectList Benefits { get; set; }
}
```

Controller set up:

```
var model = new LookupVm
{

    Benefits = new SelectList(_repository.Benefits.OrderBy(n => n.Name).ToList(), "Id", "Name")
}
```

The view:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(benefits => Model.Benefits.SelectedValue, Model.Benefits, "-Select-")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(benefits => Model.Benefits.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/391/Posts/14810/dropdownlist-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-3razor.aspx

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you're having - is there an error message? Invalid inputs are accepted? Please expand.

Comment: Hi, My drop down lists are accepted even when empty, I want the validation to stop empty/null selections and display a validation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a SelectedBenefit property to you view model

```
public class LookupVm
{
    public int SelectedBenefit { get; set;}
    public SelectList Benefits { get; set; }
}
```

Then add on top of the view

```
@model LookupVm
```

And then dropdown list must be something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBenefit, model.Benefits, "-Select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedBenefit)
```

You will get the selected id on SelectedBenefit property and it will be a required field.

Comment: Hi Estaban, I followed your example and still get no validation on the drop down :(

Comment: My lookupvm does have other select lists, would this cause confusion for "SelectedBenefit"?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you enable client side validation? That is add jquery-1.7.1.min.js, jquery.validate.min.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js. Also need to add two properties in app.setting. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326792/asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-min-js

Comment: Ahhhh, I thought client side validation was enabled by default DOH thank you so much, now everything works! :D