# ajax helpers in mvc call non-asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am developing in asp.net mvc and today I saw some strange thing in using ajax helpers.

If I use Ajax.BeginForm(...) or Ajax.ActionLink(...), they do not call (post to) the actions asynchronously, and they work as they are normal form or normal link, but when I check Request.IsAjaxRequest() in action, it returns true.

For ajax forms, I use

```
$('#createqfrm').submit(function () {...}
```

and it works fine, and send the form asynchronously.

Note: I know I have to change .live() to .on() in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min since new versions of jquery.

also here are my referenced java libs:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edited**:

Checking Request.IsAjaxRequest() and saw that it returns false.

**Action Code Added:**

```
public ActionResult GetStriing()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json("ajax called",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("ajax not called", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

**part of html code for form:**

```
<form action="/admin/xxxx/create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="handeCreateQuestionnareSuccess" id="form0" method="post">        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Title">title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Status">Status</label>
        </div>
....

 <script type="text/javascript">

        function handeCreateQuestionnareSuccess(context) {
            debugger;
            if (context) {

                $("#CreateQuestionnarieform").empty().html(context[1]);
                $("#CreateQuestionnarieform").append('<input type=hidden name=questionnarieid value=' + context[2] + '/>');

            } else {

                $("#CreateQuestionnarieform").empty().html(context[1]);

                $("form").removeData("validator");
                $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Code that submits form with ajax call:**

```
$('#createqfrm').submit(function () {

                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (context) {



                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
```

**not a solution but can notify other users:**

The problem is with jquery 1.9.0 and updates that I get from nuget for jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js I changed back to 1.8.3 and it works fine.....

Comment: How do you know they are are working like forms or links? Is the page reloaded?

Comment: no, but in result of action, i return some json , and the page shows raw json

Comment: Can you show an example of an action you are returning?

Comment: Did you check via firebuf if all scripts have been loaded successfully. Maybe there's a typo.

Comment: If this is not the case please post HTML of an ajax form, there should be an attribute `data-ajax` setted to `true`.

Comment: Did you check if all javascript files have been loaded?

Comment: And where is `#CreateQuestionnarieform`?

Comment: it never reaches to function handeCreateQuestionnareSuccess(context) to update CreateQuestionnarieform...it is below the form.

Comment: Can you show the code that submits the form?

Comment: Did you check in firebug for javascript errors? And again: did you check if all javascript files have been loaded?

Comment: simon the problem is with jquery 1.9.0 and updates that I get from nuget for jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js I changed back to 1.8.3 and it works fine.....

Comment: So again: do you have javascript errors in firebug console? If there's any error chances are big that it breaks unobtrusive ajax! Do you use jQuerys `.live()` anywhere on your page?

Comment: NO i do NOT HAVE JAVA SCRIPT ERRORS AND i DONT USE .LIVE()

Comment: Check my edited answer, there are known issues with jQuery 1.9 and unobtrusive ajax.

Comment: And looking in my file `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` shows me that it uses `.live()` which has been removed in jQuery 1.9!

Answer (score 1):

Well that sounds like `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to false. Have a look in your AppSettings-File. In section `<appsettings>` there should be:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

**EDIT:**

Just found this link after a minute of googling:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1877166.aspx/1?jquery+unobtrusive+ajax+js+error+with+jQuery+1+9+0+updated

[Unobtrusive Ajax stopped working after update jQuery to 1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391867/unobtrusive-ajax-stopped-working-after-update-jquery-to-1-9-0)

Comment: It has been set to true, if it was not, I cound not manually send form asynchronously

Comment: I mean not using ajax.beingform....but using $('#createqfrm').submit(function () {...}

Comment: This are two different things! `Ajax.BeginForm` is a HTML-Helper generatung HTML for the form. `.submit()` is a jQuery command running the submit of a form. Show your form HTML!

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I know that .live() issue .... look at 6th paragraph...thanks any way

Comment: Well you only write that you know you have to change it.. did you change it?