# why file uploader not works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i create a sample mvc application to test file upload i read this useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file) and do it but client validator works not and gives me error my all codes are:

i attached these in heder tag:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

my model:

```
public class FIleModel
{
   [Required, FileExtensions(Extensions = "csv", ErrorMessage = "Specify a CSV file. (Comma-separated values)")]
   public HttpPostedFileBase myFile { get; set; }
}
```

error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 9003 in http://localhost:6284/Scripts    
/jquery.validate.min.js
   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' 
   of undefined or null reference
```

on my view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li class="lifile">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myFile, new { type = "file" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.myFile)

                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659023/error-in-jquery-validate-js-in-mvc-4-project-with-jquery-1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For file uploading, you can use this code.

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventModel eventmodel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ 
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {

      //you can validate file here. if okay continue...

      var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photo/"), filename);
      file.SaveAs(path);
      eventmodel.Url = filename;

      _db.EventModels.AddObject(eventmodel);
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(eventmodel);
}
```

And View:

```
<div>
   Image
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
   @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.ImageUrl)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.Url )
</div>
```

Comment: what is the tyre?

Comment: I changed my answer. Tyre was remaining from my old code for one Tyre Company. Thanks for your attention.