# 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, proxy

I have developed a website which uses Ajax POST using jQuery to a PHP server.

While it works perfectly when accessed from a web browser at home, some of my Ajax requests fail when accessed from a web browser on my day job's corporate network, and I get the following error shown by Firebug: `407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )`.  Note that Chrome does not show the error but it is still blocked, and IE11 blocks it as well but I haven't been able to view the message using Development Tools due to an unrelated issue ([Error in jquery.validate.js in MVC 4 Project with jQuery 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659023/error-in-jquery-validate-js-in-mvc-4-project-with-jquery-1-9)).

I have no ability to modify anything on the corporate network, nor is it my desire to do so.  My desire is to modify the HTML/JavaScript/Headers which my server provides to eliminate blocking of the request so others do not experience this issue.

What can be done?

Comment: sounds like your work machine is not logged in at the time the ajax runs

Comment: try running CNTLM - it renegotiates proxy auth and gets a lot of stuff through the productivity firewall.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are using a complete url address in your html or jquery posts
e.g.

```
action="http://www.example.com/mydir/myfile.php"
```

Try changing the url reference so that it doesn't include the website address
e.g.

```
action="/mydir/myfile.php"
```

This also works when posting with AJAX/jquery
e.g. the code below produces the same error

```
var url1="http://www.example.com/mydir/myfile.php";
$.post(url1, function(data){alert(data);});
```

but this code doesn't

```
var dir1="/mydir/myfile.php";
$.post(dir1, function(data){alert(data);});
```

It is important to note that when you switch from the complete urls to the directories, you have to define your directory relative to your current file directory.