# Ajax submit getting 404 error but URL is correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, http-status-code-404

I have an ajax form with a submit button, but when I click on the submit button I get a 404 page not found error.

Part of my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Maps", null, ajaxOptions, new { @class = "form-search" }))
{
    ...
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
}
```

The ajaxOptions variable is defined as this:

```
var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "filter-results",
    LoadingElementId = "filter-loading",
    LoadingElementDuration = 2000,
    OnFailure = "showAjaxError",
    Url = Url.Action("Index")
};
```

This renders in my browser (Chrome) like so:

```
<form action="/Maps" class="form-search" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="showAjaxError" data-ajax-loading="#filter-loading" data-ajax-loading-duration="2000" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#filter-results" data-ajax-url="/Maps" id="form0" method="post">    <div class="well well-small">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" class="span3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-prepend pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Items Per Page</button>
            <input type="number" name="ItemsPerPage" class="span1" value="10">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The 404 error says:

```
Requested URL: /Maps
```

I can paste this into my browser and it works:

```
http://localhost:7374/Maps
```

I think I'm referencing the right javascript files - looking at the page source I see these:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

In my Web.config I have this:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check if the controller `MapsController` in action `Index` accept only `HttpGet`. because you send with `POST` method
2. need you this `Url = Url.Action("Index")`?
3. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391905/138071), jQuery in version 1.9 don't have `.live` method, and the file `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` workes with this method. if you need works with jQuery 1.9+, you have to change that.

spanish solution for point 3 ([link](http://geeks.ms/blogs/etomas/archive/2013/01/18/jquery-1-9-y-el-unobtrusive-ajax-de-asp-net-mvc.aspx)).

Comment: Another shameful mistake is forgetting the access modifier on the action method. I waster hours in debugging my codes and then realized that I haven't flagged the action method with "public".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your controller action marked with HttpGetAttribute? To my knowledge, if you are using Ajax helpers you should also add references to microsoft's ajax scripts: MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this doesn't work with the jquery **1.9.0** or **1.9.1** but does with prior versions.

Works:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Doesn't work (404 error):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```