# ASP.NET MVC4 Ajax.ActionLink replaces entire page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-ajax

In my view I have:

```
 @section Header {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }

<div>
    <div>@Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "CurrentTime", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "some_div", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter })</div>
</div>

<div id="some_div">

</div>
```

In header of the result page I see these scripts are referenced:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

The link looks there like this:

```
<div><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="after" data-ajax-update="#some_div" href="/Tournament/CurrentTime">Test</a></div>
```

In the controller:

```
public string CurrentTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

In my web.config (in the root of the application):

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

My problem is: whenever I click the link, the result (current time) always replaces entire page - it is not inserted in / after / before some_div.
Thanks

Comment: look at the errors console in chrome or firefox. Probably you script is not loaded

Comment: @Garath: Thanks! The FireBug found this:  

TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
  

$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {

But I did not edit the script (at least I'm not aware of that). Please how shall I fix that? It is in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your comment the answer is easy you have to upgrade your jQuery. The `on` method is working from jquery 1.7. I suggest to use jquery 1.7.2 because mvc scripts have sometimes problems with higher versions

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. Is there any chance to use jquery.unobtrusive-ajax together with newer versions of jQuery?

Comment: You can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391867/unobtrusive-ajax-stopped-working-after-update-jquery-to-1-9-0.

Comment: There is an update of jquery validation https://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation/1.11.0