# JQuery Unobtrusive AJAX Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-ajax

It stopped working recently and I'm not sure why (ASP .NET MVC 4, jQuery 1.8.3). All things using unobtrusive ajax on my site (validation, Html.Ajax, Ajax.ActionLink, etc) simply do a regular post instead of an AJAX post.

My only clue is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:96
```

In the Chrome debugger.

I've tried updating the nuget package.

How can I troubleshoot further or at least get some useful clues?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Setting a break point at line 95?

Comment: are you sure that a jquery 1.9+ file hasn't snuck in somewhere?  try adding jquery.migrate to your site and see if it works again

Comment: No breakpoint is hit (presumably because it's invalid syntax...)

Comment: no, didn't update anything...just suddenly stopped working

Comment: checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391867/unobtrusive-ajax-stopped-working-after-update-jquery-to-1-9-0