# Error "SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with the following code. The *console.log* output is:

My requested URL via a JavaScript Ajax request is the "login.php":

```
 <?php include('init.php');
    use Login\LoginService;

    #include(__DIR__.'/Login/LoginService.php');

    global $pdo;
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    if (!empty($username)) {
        $test = new LoginService();
        $user = $test->getUsersLogin($username);
        if (!empty($user) && $user[0]['login'] == $username) {
            $json = json_encode(array("success" => 1));
            echo $json;
        } else {
            $json = json_encode(array("success" => 0));
            echo $json;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

My Ajax request via JavaScript:

```
$(() => {
    $('.login-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 500,
            url: '/src/login.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            success: (data) => {
                try {
                    var jso = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(jso);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: (data) => {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Why is the response from the PHP `{"success":1}` not right? What is the problem?

> SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: You're not sending the form data => `!empty($username)` fails -=> PHP sends back an empty response => Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Whe I add the dataType: 'json' to my javascript. I become the following error: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: @JonathanFuchs Because then `data` has already been parsed as JSON, so parsing an already parsed object will fail.

Comment: I add the data tag and the response is following: {"success":1}

But the error: SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: Related: `error: (data) =>` - data will never be sent to the `error` handler as the error handler means something went wrong with the *request* itself - so `JSON.parse(data)` will always give an error.   Check the documentation for the correct parameters: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Useful tip:  know the difference between JSON (a string) and a Javascript Object - *specifically* how they appear in the browser console when debugging.   Then you can `console.log(data)` and you'll know immediately that it's already an object.

Comment: I was getting this error after I had upgraded jQuery to latest version 3.6. Later on, I found out that I had not upgraded `Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax` nuget package as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539422/465053).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you write `dataType: "json"` then jQuery will automatically parse your response as JSON *before* it comes to the "success" function. This is [described in the jQuery `$.ajax` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Therefore, `data` is *already an object*. You cannot pass an object into `JSON.parse()` - it requires a string.

Instead of

```
var jso = JSON.parse(data); console.log(jso);
```

you can just write

```
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do it to avoid this error:

```
myFunction(data: string) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(data);
  }
   catch (e) {
   console.log(e); 
  }
}
```