# Handling multiple $.ajax calls simultaneously in .ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading

I have the following method in my GenericHandler.ashx:

```
private void T1()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Ctx.Response.Write(Serializer.Serialize(new { foo = "bar" }));
}
```

If I make 2 `$.ajax`-calls to the handler simultaneously, I will get the first response after 2 seconds, and the next after 4.

Is there any way to make my GenericHandler.ashx handle both ajax calls simultaneously?

Comment: Are you seriously `Sleep`ing in a web service?

Comment: He's using it for testing purposes I think

Comment: @cHao Yes, for demo purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[What you seem to need is a Asynchronous HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx)**

> During processing of an asynchronous HTTP handler, ASP.NET puts the
>   thread that would ordinarily be used for the external process back
>   into the thread pool until the handler receives a callback from the
>   external process. This can prevent thread blocking and improve
>   performance, because only a limited number of threads can be executing
>   at the same time. If many users request synchronous HTTP handlers that
>   rely on external processes, the operating system can quickly run out
>   of threads because many threads are blocked and waiting for an
>   external process.

You current method's body would be located in the `StartAsyncTask` method body of the provided example

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax once during your session. Check whether it's already loaded:

```
if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
{
    Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
}
```

Comment: What exactly would the script do?

Comment: Checks whether the requested header has already rendered the unobtrusive jquery file or not. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326792/asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-min-js

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your parameters for $.ajax, I'm guessing your need to set async to true.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "page.ashx",
   async: true
});
```

Also, please be aware different browsers react differently dependant on how many requests it allows at once.

[Check out async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Why would I want to make a synchronous call? The whole point with $.ajax is to make use of the async part.

Comment: Are you calling a method with a single ajax call twice or is it two code blocks one after the other in one method? I think the behaviour could be cause it waits for the method to complete. Please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4428894/2637902